# What is the proper way of stating that a function fires an event in a Polymer element?

Tags: javascript, polymer, documentation, polymer-1.0

Given the following, incredibly simplified, custom Polymer element, how should I document the 'added-numbers' event that is fired by the 'add' function so that it appears in the documentation pages generated by `iron-component-page` (image below)?

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host { display: block; }
    </style>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-element',
      properties: {
        // properties go here
      },
      /**
      * Just adds two numbers together and fires an event.
      * @param {Number} a The first number
      * @param {Number} b The second number
      * @fires my-element#added-numbers I WANT TO DOCUMENT THE EVENT HERE
      */
      add: function (a, b) {
        var c = a + b;
        this.fire('added-numbers', { value: c });
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

[image: screenshot of auto generated docs page]

The Polymer documentation [itself](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/documentation#events) shows how to document an event as if it is a function (with a summary and parameters), but doesn't show an example of how to document a function that is expected to fire an event (or more than one).

I have looked at the JSDoc standard for JavaScript documentation and that has a [`@fires`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-fires.html) tag that appears to be what I am after (and I have tried to used it above), but it is ignored when the doc pages are generated.

I am using Polymer version 1.9 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `@event` annotation. just add a new comment block before your function or anywhere else inside your element

```
 /**
  * Just adds two numbers together and fires an event.
  * @param {Number} a The first number
  * @param {Number} b The second number
  */
  add: function (a, b) {
    var c = a + b;
    this.fire('added-numbers', { value: c });
  }

 /**
 * Fired when .....
 *
 * @event event-name
 * @param {{eventParam:boolean}} detail -
 *     eventParam: true if .....
 */
```

Comment: Thanks Hyyan! I just want to clarify something before accepting your answer though: with the first suggestion nothing is added to the documentation page, but it is with the second one. Is that what you'd expect?

Comment: @Ben yes this what I would expect, the first one will not work as `@event` must has its own comment block , fixed that now

Comment: That's a shame but at least I know now. And actually the Polymer docs were spot on, just needed to be clearer that it should be a stand alone comment block! Thanks @Hyyan